# String.format in FreeMarker

Tags: freemarker

I need to output a few values in FreeMarker using `printf`-esque parameters equivalent to this:

```
String.format("%04d", index);
String.format("%s (%s)", lastName, firstName);
```

I've tried doing the following, which fails with an error:

```
${String.format("%04d", index)}
```

It fails to locate `String`.

What's the recommended way of approaching these formatting issues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a template language, so:

```
${index?string('0000')}
${lastName} (${firstName})
```